# Terraform: How can I run a function on each element of a collection?

Tags: terraform

I have a section in my terraform module which reads text from multiple files and joins them together.

```
foo = join("\n", [
  file('path/to/file1.txt'),
  file('path/to/file2.txt'),
  file('path/to/file3.txt'),
])
```

Its cumbersome to always list every file, and I would like to switch to using: `fileset("path/to", "*.txt")` to list all the files.

However, this gives me a list of file paths, which I can't give to `file()`. Is there some way I can run `file()` on each element of this list?

In other languages there is usually some `map()` function which is used to transform the elements of a collection, by calling a function on each item. I can't find anything like this in terraform. The closest thing I've found, is `format_list()` but that doesn't do what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to convert your list of file function returns from hardcoded inputs into a list of file function returns from dynamic inputs sourced from the `fileset` function, we can use a custom lambda for that:

```
[for text_file in fileset("path/to", "*.txt") : file(text_file)]
```

and this return value would be equivalent to:

```
[
  file('path/to/file1.txt'),
  file('path/to/file2.txt'),
  file('path/to/file3.txt'),
  ...
]
```

which you can input as an argument to `join` and assign to `foo` as you are doing in the question. More information on for expressions (the specific type of lambda function used here) can be found in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html). Note that these for expressions have implicit returns and are not "void" functions, making them equivalent to `map` as you requested, and not equivalent to an `each`.